# Scaling background image which is splitted in multiple parts

Tags: html, css, image, background

I've searched and tested a lot the last days and single problems I could solve more or less with success. But all problems together I can't get to work.

My problem: I have an image, which is splitted with Photoshop into slices. All these slices I would like to put on my website as background. The "complete picture" should be stretched and scaled automatically to the window size.

The reason why I want single slices: I want the user to be able to click on a part of the whole picture and a not shown div with additional information shows up.

Yesterday I had the following test with a picture sliced into 4 parts

### x | x

### x | x

(There is no border between the picture parts.)

As my window got smaller only the right slices got scaled until the window border reached the left picture parts. Then the left pictures got scaled, too.

So, all in all, I would like to:
- place picture parts as background images
- put a link on the images to disabled divs to show add. information
- proportionally scale all slices together, so that the whole picture always fits the window

I hope I could desribe my problem in understandable English.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you could do like this

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper div');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.getAttribute('data-nr'));    
  })
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/animals/1);
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/animals/2);
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/animals/3);
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/animals/4);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div data-nr=1></div>
  <div data-nr=2></div>
  <div data-nr=3></div>
  <div data-nr=4></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for late response...It's exactly what I needed. I've successfully changed this to 5 parts (2 in top row, 3 in bottom row)